# Unknown ActiveSync Device keeps locking account out

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I have an unknown ActiveSync device attempting to authenticate against an account and locking it out repeatedly. I would like to set a rule which prevents this particular DeviceID from attempting to log in but do not know if that is possible.

IP address has changed a few times so I don't think I can block it in that fashion.

Any ways to prevent this? I've even disabled activesync on that mailbox/user but it still allows authentication attempts to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Set ActiveSync to quarantine. That will stop it from synchronising. 
Then get the user to find the device they are obviously no longer using and remove their account.

A more evil answer would be to change the password back to what it was in the past, so the device is able to successfully sync, then send a wipe command.

Comment: So my concern is that they will not find the device - they refuse to acknowledge it even exists. I was able to go in to the IIS logs and find the DeviceID, User-Agent, etc. of the device but can't find a way to enforce a block on that. If I had the mac address, this would be easy lol